# como executo sem tirar o int do codigo?

Tags: python-3.x

```
codigo = input('Digite um numero: ')

for i in codigo:
    print(f'{i} |', end='')
```

gera esse resultado, ok

```
> Digite um numero: 21853
> 2 |1 |8 |5 |3 |
> Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

abaixo acrescento int ele gera erro, como resolveria sem tirar o int do codigo

```
codigo = int(input('Digite um numero: '))

for i in codigo:
    print(f'{i} |', end='')
```

gera esse resultado, erro!

```
for i in codigo:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Você pode editar a pergunta para fazer as correções.

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar.

Comment: Qual seria o motivo para usar int()? Pelo seu código simplesmente parece que o int ali não é necessário, você poderia converter para int() depois do for(), mas ao invés disso ficou que converte uma string para int e depois é obrigado a converter de volta para str. Pode explicar melhor o problema Ricardo? cc @Lucas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já tentou fazer uma [`conversão`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-convert-data-types-in-python-3-pt) (cast) para [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html)?

Segue um exemplo de como pode ser implementado:

```
codigo = int(input('Digite um numero: '))

for i in str(codigo):
    print(f'{i} |', end='')
```

Veja que agora é necessário tratar caso o usuário digite um valor não-numérico (por exemplo a letra <kbd>a</kbd>) então será necessário tratar este caso. Afim de evitar o erro:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'

Em Python usa-se o comando [`try/except`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/errors.html) para fazer esta operação.

Segue um exemplo de como tratar este fluxo:

```
while True:
    try:
        codigo = int(input("Digite um numero: "))
        for i in str(codigo):
            print(f'{i} |', end='')
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Pff! Não foi possível representar o valor lido como número. Tente novamente...")
```